# Json Response - Accessing objects in an array

Tags: arrays, json, rest-assured

I'm attempting to access an object in an Json response, but not sure how. How can I access ID 11 using rest-assured, where ObjID1 and ObjID2 are unique UUID's?

```
       "ObjID1": [
            {
                "ID": "11",
                "NAME": "XYZ",
                "GENDER": "M"
            }
        ]

        "ObjID2": [
            {
                "ID": "12",
                "NAME": "Z",
                "GENDER": "F"
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

To assert element's value you can use

```
then().body("ObjID1.ID[0]", equalTo("11"))
```

Indexing `ID` field with `[0]` allows you to get the ID of first JSON Object in the Array.

If you want to get this value for further processing then you can extract it like this:

```
JsonPath path = JsonPath.from("json file or json String");
List<HashMap<String, Object>> listOfJsonObjects = path.get("ObjID1");
```

We parsed the JSON and by using the `path.get` method we save Array of JSON Objects inside List of HashMaps. Each element in the list is the JSON Object.

In order to access first JSON Object you can use

```
HashMap<String, Object> jsonObject = listOfJsonObjects.get(0);
```

and then, using classic HashMap methods you can get specific element in the JSON Object like this:

```
jsonObject.get("ID");
```

The above will return `"11"`
Note that you will have to make a cast to String to get the value. Values in the HashMap are objects because JSON Objects in the array may contain nested Arrays or Objects.

```
String firstId = (String) jsonObject.get("ID");
```